# Incorrect syntax near '/'. in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to apply divide operator in this statement, but it throws an error

> Incorrect syntax near '/'

I am using SQL Server 2012

```
(select count(distinct emploc) as test from location) / 
(select count(emploc) from location)
```

Comment: Add another level of `SELECT` at the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `select` before the expression:

```
select ((select count(distinct emploc) as test from location) /
        (select count(emploc) from location)
       )
```

A SQL query begins with `select`.  In a few cases, you can start with `(select . . .` (such as when using `union all`).  The SQL parser is not a generic expression parser for arithmetic expressions, so `select 2/1` works, but not `2/1`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use it in single query

```
SELECT count(distinct emploc)/convert(float,count(emploc)) as Test from location
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below

```
SELECT 
(select count(distinct emploc) as test from location)/(select count(emploc) from location)
```

Though you cam make it in a single query like

```
select count(distinct emploc) / count(emploc) from location
```

Answer (score -1):

i've found this error while executing the proc
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure proc1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '('.
here is script wher wk and dd found incorrect syntax
create procedure proc1
 @name VARCHAR(50), -- Database name
 @path VARCHAR(256), -- Path for backup files
 @databasepath VARCHAR(256), -- Path for backup files
 @fileName VARCHAR(256), -- Filename for backup
 @fileDate VARCHAR(200), -- Used for file name
 @DeleteDateBAK DATETIME = DATEADD (wk,-1,GETDATE()), -- Cutoff date
 @DeleteDateTRN DATETIME = DATEADD(dd,-2,GETDATE()); -- Cutoff date
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50); -- Database name
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256); -- Path for backup files
DECLARE @databasepath VARCHAR(256); -- Path for backup files
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256); -- Filename for backup
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(200); -- Used for file name
DECLARE @DeleteDateBAK DATETIME = DATEADD(wk,-1,GETDATE()); -- Cutoff date
DECLARE @DeleteDateTRN DATETIME = DATEADD(dd,-2,GETDATE()); -- Cutoff date

-- Path to backups.
SET @path = 'G:\backup\DXC_bkp_plan & Maintainance\';

-- Get date to include in file name.
SELECT @fileDate =  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),120),'-','*'),' ','*'),':','')
SET @fileDate = @fileDate +  '_'
SET @fileDate = @fileDate + (CONVERT(VARCHAR(200),ABS(CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(BINARY(8), NEWID()))) % 10000000))

-- Dynamically get each database on the server.
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM master.sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb','ApexSQLBackupCentralRepository','Career_Progression','CensusDB','CONTECTUAL','CONTROL','DASHBOARD','DAY_DASHBOARD','dbdgetEnglishForHP-CMS','DGET_','DGET_DWH','DH','Dummy_DS','GOA','GoogleAnalytics','INSTDB','Mig','Migrated','Qual','RND','TripuraNCS','Test');

OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name;

-- Loop through the list to backup each database.
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
      -- Build the path and file name.
      SET @databasepath = @path + @name + N'\';
      SET @fileName = @databasepath + @name + '*backup*' + @fileDate + '.BAK';

```
  EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @databasepath

  -- Backup the database.
  BACKUP DATABASE @name TO  DISK = @fileName WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10;

  -- Purge old backup files from disk.
  EXEC master.sys.xp_delete_file 0,@path,'BAK',@DeleteDateBAK,1;
  EXEC master.sys.xp_delete_file 0,@path,'TRN',@DeleteDateTRN,1;

  -- Loop to the next database.
  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name;
```

END
-- Clean up.
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;